# Boost interprocess: how to create map<string, string> with custome allocator?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, boost-interprocess

So I faaced `map<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MyMap;` from [interprocess tutoral](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_map) I wonder how to make std::string, std::string map?

Comment: Eh, you linked to a Boost.Variant tutorial, so it's no wonder it didn't help you with Boost.Interprocess much. ;-]

Comment: You can't use `std::string` but `basic_string` can easily be stored into shared memory. You need to change the `typedef KeyType` to be the same as `MappedType` in that tutorial.